# Alternative for Notepad++?

Tags: macos, applications, software-recommendation

I really love Notepad++ and I haven't found an alternative for it yet. TextMate and TextWrangler aren't quite there yet. Specifically,  two things that I want that are not in TextMate:

- variable highlighting
- bracket highlighting

Can you suggest an alternative editor for OS X?

Comment: Textmate "quite there yet"? Seriously? I suggest you go back and look again ;)

Comment: Actually I enjoy TextMate much more than Notepad++. Weird!

Comment: As Matthew is pointing out in his answer, just tell us what you miss in TextMate or TextWrangler that you would like to find in your mac text editor.

Comment: TextMate bracket selection can be done when you're in a bracketed section. [See this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1278700/bracket-highlighting-in-textmate-javascript).

Comment: The other feature isn't "variable highlighting" it's "show all matches for current selection". Outside of the Find All box I don't think there's a way to do this in TextMate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've recently started using [Atom](https://atom.io) - it's modern, lightweight, and does a metric buttload of different things.

Answer (score 7):

It's not clear from your question what exactly you're missing -- I use Notepad++ on the PC and find both TextMate and TextWrangler to be reasonable replacements -- but you'll likely appreciate either TextWrangler's big brother **[BBEdit 9](http://www.barebones.com/products/bbedit/)** or, if you can put up with its alpha nature, **[Sublime Text 2](http://www.sublimetext.com/2)**.

Answer (score 4):

[Sublime Text 2](http://www.sublimetext.com) seems to be the real powerhouse for people that are not satisfied with the heavy guns of Mac editors:

- [BBEdit](http://www.barebones.com/products/bbedit/) is now on version 10 and "still doesn't suck" (you mentioned it's free mini incarnation - [TextWrangler](http://www.barebones.com/products/textwrangler/))
- [TextMate](http://macromates.com) (either the venerable v.1 or the long unfinished but now open sourced v.2)

[Marco Arment did a nice job](http://www.marco.org/2012/08/10/next-text-editor) of rounding up not only the why but some other editors to consider with [Chocolat](http://chocolatapp.com) leading the pack behind ST/BB.

Answer (score 1):

You should also take a look at [Sublime 2](http://www.sublimetext.com/blog/articles/sublime-text-2-public-alpha), even if it is stll in public alpha, and [Smultron](http://www.peterborgapps.com/smultron/). Smultron also had a Freeware Spin-Off called 'Fraise' which is now discontinued.

Answer (score 1):

One of my former colleagues swears by [jEdit](http://www.jedit.org/) - cross-platform, flexible, and friendly.

Answer (score 1):

Editra on Mac is free, open-source, highly configurable and offers bracket highlighting.  I don't think it offers variable highlighting however.

All in all, it's my favorite simple text editor and viewer on Mac.

Answer (score 0):

Ive had the same dilemma. I mostly use [TextWrangler](http://www.barebones.com/products/textwrangler/), but the interface is archaic. You could try [Kod](http://kodapp.com/), which has tabs and other nicetities.

Answer (score -3):

If you use java(not java script) there is something called eclipse. It has a built in compiler. A Couple tutorial and you will have mastered it!

Comment: This is an IDE, not an editor.

Comment: But you *could* use Eclipse as an editor, right?