# Alternative to Notepad++ with saving on the fly

Tags: applications

Any text written in a Notepad++ tab will be saved immediately and recovered after re-opening. (It saves them, in my case, into `OneDrive\Documents\Notepad++\backup`) 
That's pretty convenient. You should not care where to save a file, how to name it so on, so on.

Is there some MacOS Notepad++ alternatives which have the same feature?

Comment: Why would Apple need an alternative? Notepad++ works well and with the Cloud across devices.

Comment: @SolarMike, could you add details please? I don't get it.

Comment: emacs will do this

Comment: There are [a lot of text editors for macOS](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/10686/alternative-for-notepad) (and several Q& on AD about text editor options in general), Nearly all of these editors use some kind of recovery mechanism to protect against crash-related data loss.

Comment: @nohillside, that's not the case when we lost something by accident. That's the case when create a document and you don't need it to be saved. This is required in the most of editors.

Comment: @mmmmmm, not really. When you press "new" it ask a filename, location, etc.

Comment: @Kirby it can be configured not too - I would have said see Aquamacs but that might be a bit out of date

Comment: @mmmmmm, Uh, I see, thanks for this note.

Answer (score 2):

[BBEdit](https://www.barebones.com/products/bbedit/download.html) will re-open un-saved documents on re-launch.

However, I would dispute that *"You should not care where to save a file, how to name it, and so on".*

Having memorable filenames in a hierarchical organization is essential, if you want to find the files again. Having 1000 files named "Untitled N" in the same folder is no use to anyone.

> (It saves them in some temp folder)

Documents that are formally unsaved are just saved to the Saved Application State folder in the user Library. There's no guarantee that this folder (or any other **temp** folder) won't be emptied.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using [Obsidian.app](https://obsidian.md/), which I have been very happy with.

It saves automatically, and also (optionally) syncs with your iCloud storage, so that your files are available also on mobile.